# CiviCRM integration with bespoke custom CMS?

Tags: integration

Can CiviCRM be integrated into a bespoke custom built cms, I see that you can download it for drupal, wordpress and joomla but our cms was built specifically for our non for profit, if someone could help me with this that would be fantastic

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that you could build an integration component to make it work with your custom cms, but it probably wouldn't be worth the effort.

Your best bet would probably be to use the api to accomplish an integration on the pieces you care about.  The api includes methods for most functions, including inserting, updating, deleting and retrieving data using php, rest, smarty and javascript interfaces.  As well as html/js snippets for forms to be embedded into your cms html.  See:
http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/api#explorer
log in as demo/demo.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to skin up a Drupal CMS to have the same look/navigation as your bespoke system and push people through to it for Contribution pages etc. The user would probably not notice as they move from yoursite.com to eg donate.yoursite.com

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is possible but you would be in not well-charted territory. I'm assuming you are a developer. You'd need have a thorough understanding of how the CMS works under the hood.

Have a look at 
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/Invoke.php

I am not certain if CiviDesk is maintaining a "standalone" (CMS-free) fork.

Along the lines of the other the other replies... you'd probably be better off adding single-sign-on features to your CMS for a seamless integration with a minimal drupal instance that houses Civi.